# Facebook ticker for android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-layout

I want to use Facebook ticker to show currently played audio file name of my android app Like spotify.
I want to continuously change the ticker as audio file changes 
I search on google i dont find any tutorial or samples. please share how can i achieve this ticker into my app I am new please guide me Waiting for reply

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must implement your application with Open Graph API. There is a built-in action called "listen".

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#listen

Comment: To use this Built in action i have to submit the Form?

Comment: i just need to post a small message on fb ticker that i am listening xyz song on xyz android application and for that i have to submit form? what a tedious procedure

Comment: I have submitted the form can you please tell me what are the next steps i have to follow and can you please share sample code to post on FB ticker

Comment: To publish an action, you need to make a HTTP post to:
    `https://graph.facebook.com/me/music.listens?song=[song object URL]`